# Combine the information of two tables into a single Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I need to read data for an external database (I cannot modify the table structure) with the two following tables:

Table1

- Key (primary key)
- Field1

Table2

- Key (primary key)
- Field2

Is it possible to combine these two tables into a single Django Model that looks like:

Model:

- Key (primary key)
- Field1
- Field2

Additional information:

The keys of the entries in Table2 are a subset of the entries in Table1. So for any entry in Table2 there is a matching entry in Table1, but not viceversa

Work so far:

I have a one model for each table (1 and 2) and Table1 model has a "field2" @property that looks up the corresponding information in the Table2 model.

Also, I can do this at the sql level with the following query:

```
SELECT
  table1.key,
  table1.field1,
  table2.field2,
FROM
  table1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
      ON table1.key=table2.key
ORDER BY table1.key ASC
```

===
Solution implementation details update after seeing some of the answers:

From [Daniel Roseman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36179637/2238289)

I ended up with two models:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    field1 = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Table1'

    def field2_value(self):
        try:
            return self.field2.value
        except Model2.DoesNotExist:
            return None


class Model2(models.Model):
    key = models.OneToOneField(Model1, primary_key=True, db_column='key',
                               related_name='field2')
    field2 = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Table2'
```

While it is not exactly what I had originally in mind when I asked this question, it meets my desired use case

Also, here are the corresponding admin classes:

```
class Model2Admin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Model2


@admin.register(Model1)
class Model1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (Model2Admin,)
    list_display = ('key', 'field1', 'field2_value')
    # Loads the related property in one SQL call instead of one call per entry
    list_select_related = ('field2',)
```

Thanks [KaaN SARIKAYA for your great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36182293/2238289). I didn't know that I could create a view of the two tables. If I could modify the database structure I would opt for your option.

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking, it may help to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be to keep these as two models, but have the primary key of the second be a OneToOneField to the first.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot merge the model because they are 2 physical tables, django models are tied by the database table names so you couldn't do what you want. If you have the control for those external database tables and have the right to modify them, you should modify the schema first and merge the data. If you don't want to or you cannot modify anything, your current way is OK.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a table_view on sql and make an abstract model on django . Suppose you have 2 pyhsical models and tables.

SQL CODE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW combine_two_model_view AS 
SELECT
mt1.name as mt1_name,
mt2.name as mt2_name,
mt1.pub_date as mt1_pub_date
.
.
.
.

FROM modeltable1 mt1

 LEFT JOIN modeltable2 mt2 ON mt2.id = mt1.id


ALTER TABLE combine_two_model_view
OWNER TO dbuser;
```

we created sql view table. now, we will create an abstract model

in your models.py:

```
class YourModelsCombine(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        db_table = "combine_two_model_view"

    mt1_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mt2_name = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    mt1_pub_date = models.DateTimeField("Publish Date", auto_now_add=True)
    mt2_pub_date = models.DateField("Updated Date", auto_now=True)
    mt1_integer = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    #etc
```

attention: make sure your table view variable names and model variable names must be same. Finally;
in your admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(YourModelsCombine)
```

You will see combine of two tables on your django-admin
I hope this helps to you